# Add headers in all outgoing http requests using request module of ExpressJS, is it possible?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, http-headers, httprequest

I'm using the `request` module for NodeJS.

I was wondering,
Instead of adding the headers in every request by hand like the docs.

ex.

```
var options = {
  url: myuRL,
  headers: {
    'myHeader': 'headerVal'
  }
}

request(options ,callback);
```

**Is it possible with a middleware or something to inject the headers in ALL requests?**

I tried by creating this middleware:

```
const addHeaders = function (req, res, next) {
  req.header('myHeader', 'MyVal');
  next();
};
module.exports = addHeaders;
```

It works on all http requests except those created with the `request` module.

NOTE: I mean to all me **outgoing** request not to the incoming.

Answer (score 1):

From https://www.npmjs.com/package/request#convenience-methods:

`request.defaults(options)` 
This method returns a wrapper around the normal request API that defaults to whatever options you pass to it.

```
//requests using baseRequest() will set the 'x-token' header 
var baseRequest = request.defaults({
  headers: {'x-token': 'my-token'}
})
```

You can wrap the request module inside your own module to prevent redefining the header every time, for example, create `myRequest.js`

```
var request = require('request');
var myRequest = request.defaults({
  headers: {'x-token': 'my-token'}
})
module.exports = exports = myRequest;
```

[EDIT] Working example:

**myRequest.js**

```
const request = require('request');
const myRequest = request.defaults({
  headers: {'x-token': 'my-token'}
});
 module.exports = exports = myRequest;
```

**index.js**

```
const myRequest = require('./myRequest.js');
const options = {
  url: 'https://google.com'
};
myRequest(options, (err, res, body) => {
  if (err) {
    console.error(err);
  }
  else {
    console.log(res.req._headers);
  }
});
```

**Running `index.js`**:

```
$ node ./index.js
{ 'x-token': 'my-token',
referer: 'https://google.com/',
host: 'www.google.com' }
```

I've pushed the example to https://github.com/agoldis/stackoverflow_37549654

Comment: @VassilisPits should work, check out the edited answer :)

Comment: You set the headers when you run the app?

Comment: @VassilisPits The headers are set in `myRequest.js` - every use of `myRequest` will set the headers accordingly. Isn't that what you've asked for?

Comment: Yes and thx for the support, it doesn't work though still. I'll figure it out and come back. Upvote though